# Getting 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError' exception in graphql

Tags: java, graphql

Here is the pom.xml

```xml
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>        
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>        
  <version>3.1.2</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependency>             
 <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>           
 <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>             
 <version>2.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

when trying to execute below code, getting the error. The rest api is returning the response.However the below code is throwing the error.

```java
public RefundOrderDetailsResponse
  getRefundOrderDetails(String employeeId, String orderId) {
  UriComponentsBuilder builder =
    UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(refundOrderDetailsUrl)
      .queryParam("employeeId", employeeId)
      .queryParam("orderId", orderId);
  ResponseEntity<RefundOrderDetailsResponse>
    response = restTemplate.getForEntity(builder.toUriString(),
    RefundOrderDetailsResponse.class);
  return response.getBody();
}

package com.octanner.commerceconfig.dto.refundorder;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class RefundOrderDetailsResponse {
    private String employeeId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String orderId;
    private Double pointBalance;
    private String orderStatus;
    private boolean refundable;
}
```

Comment: When you get `NoSuchMethodError` it generally means you're using incompatible versions of dependencies. Spring Boot 3.1.2 seems to depend on entirely different libraries and different versions for OAuth2 support, so probably your current dependency on `org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.5.2.RELEASE` is simply the wrong thing for Spring Boot 3.1.2.

Comment: It is best to use the boot versions of them. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/core.html . There you can leave out the version as the parent knows best with which version it is compatible with.